# How to prevent jQuery functions from not running if a preceding function fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with jQuery functions not running if a preceding function failed for example:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // this function failed to run because the dependency file wasn't loaded
});


jQuery(function($) {
    // fails to run unless all preceding function succeed
});


jQuery(function($) {
    // fails to run unless all preceding function succeed
});
```

I'm doing this because they're all small chunks of code, each one for a jquery plugin used on my site so one for a slider another one for a drop down menu ..., for example if a page without a slider I'm not loading the slider plugin so all everything after the slider function fails to run.

so what should I do so jquery ignores failing function ?

and thanks in advance.

Comment: That behavior has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `catch` block to catch the error, or use `if`s to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: so if my slider function uses .superfish() how can I use apply what you said to it ? sorry I'm new to jQuery.